# Converting an OpenGL transformation matrix to work on a CATransformLayer

Tags: ios, opengl-es, matrix-multiplication, catransform3d, catransformlayer

I've been using an [Augmented Reality SDK from String](http://www.poweredbystring.com/) for a project. Basically this SDK passes back a bunch of markers for images that it recognises, and an associated OpenGL matrix transform that outlines where the marker image is located in 3D space within the iPhone's camera view. What I'm trying to do is to map a `CATransformLayer` against the scene so that it appears properly oriented on the marker image and play back a video in it's place. I thought that I could do this using an `AVPlayerLayer` sitting inside a `CATransformLayer` that has the matrix transform (converted to a `CATransform3D`) applied to it.

Best I can tell, this doesn't work particularly well — I can't seem to get a logical mapping between the original OpenGL matrix and the matrix behind the `CATransform3D`.

You can see that it's pretty messed up doing a direct conversion between the marker transform and a `CATransform3D` object (the blue bit is my layer):

[image: Screenshot of the current state of this issue]

I assumed that they were the same (I've been told a few times that they're identical due to `CALayer` GL backing). Is this true? Am I missing something?

I can drop back to rendering my video as a texture into the scene, but it'd be great to keep things high level if possible — any ideas/comments/thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert 3D OpenGL matrix transforms to CoreAnimation CATransform3Ds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887995/how-do-i-convert-3d-opengl-matrix-transforms-to-coreanimation-catransform3ds)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10952866/852487) answer.  It should do what you need.